# wrapping text in two spans in their lines

Tags: css, html

I have two spans in a div

```
<div>
  <span class="span1">  text 1 text1 <span>
  <span class="span2"> text2 is a long text text2 is a long text text2 is a long text <span>
<div>
```

Now I want the text in span2 to wrap around from where the span2 starts not in span 1 itself

so it should'nt be like

```
   text1 text1 text2 is a long text 
   text2 is a long text text2 is a long text
```

I want it to be

```
   text1 text2 is a long text 
   text1 text2 is a long text text2 is a long text
```

How do i possibly achieve this. I have tried having spans with property display:block, but it doesn't seem to work on IE.

Also I dont want to have two separate divs because I want the background color on both spans to be same height and since height of span2 is variable i cant have consistency on background color height on both spans.

Thanks,

Comment: How should any code know to break the second span's text at `text2 is a long text`?

Comment: float:left; display:block; clear:...   ?

Comment: Your markup is invalid. First you would need to close your /spans.

Also post the CSS you're using and possibly a JSfiddle.

Comment: I am not very sure if I see a typo from your description. how could text1 got wrapped? you probably want to achieve that using table tag

Comment: It's html, not kitchen cooking. You'll have to javascript with regular-expression manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
span {float:left;clear:both;border:1px solid red}
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/xAFf5/

It this is not what you want and really want to 'split' your spans to trim some parts of text then re-render them in another design :: you'll have to javascript with regular-expression manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP is trying to communicate is simply that he/she wishes to have each span rendered on a new line. If I am correct then the following will work.

**Close your `span` and `div` tags:**

```
<div>
    <span class="span1">span 1 content </span>
    <span class="span2">span 2 content</span>
</div>
```

**Make those spans `display:block`**

```
.span1, .span2 {display:block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waMM2/

---

FWIW unless you need the spans to have different class names it would be better the give them the same one. E.G:

```
<div>
    <span class="block">span 1 content </span>
    <span class="block">span 2 content</span>
</div>
```

CSS: `.block {display:block;}`

or it may be appropriate to target all child spans of a particular div:

```
<div class="blockspans">
    <span>span 1 content</span>
    <span>span 2 content</span>
</div>
```

CSS: `.blockspans span {display:block;}`

Comment: If i'am correct, the span in display:block will float left, so, next span will be disposed beside, resulting in same layout has inlined.